# EXC_BAD_ACCESS / KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS related to orientation changes

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uideviceorientation

I have a weird problem. I got an error report that said that the app crashed related to an orientation change. The problem is that I haven't signed up to any orientation events at all in the app code. The only thing related to orientation changes I have is:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return IS_IPAD ? YES : interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

...on all view controllers to make sure it changes orientation on iPad but not iPhone. And the error happened on an iPhone.

IS_IPAD comes from this:

```
#ifdef UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM
    #define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#else
    #define IS_IPAD (false)
#endif
```

**It seems `-[UIWindow _updateInterfaceOrientationFromDeviceOrientation:]` calls some object that doesn't exist anymore. What object can that be if I haven't signed up for any orientation related notifications?**

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you can get steps for reproducing the crash, try running with zombies enabled and it should lead you to the object that's the target of the `objc_msgSend` call.

Comment: @PhillipMills The problem is that I can't reproduce the error myself.

Comment: It's hard to guess (obviously) but the fact that it's handling a "resume" makes me wonder whether your controller's view was unloaded in the background.  You might be able to get this behaviour by creating a sub-view in code and not zeroing its pointer when the view unloads.  (When trying to reproduce it, make sure you trigger a memory warning -- on an **old** iOS system -- while the app is in the background...especially if you have a modal controller visible.)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue and am seeing an almost identical stack trace.

Answer (score -2):

The method you're using is deprecated. The method `shouldAutorotate` is the new autorotation support method. I tried this and it worked as you want:

```
-(BOOL) shouldAutorotate{
    return IS_IPAD ? YES : [self preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation] == UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I don't have any problem with depreciated methods, please read the question again.